# Reading a variable in a for loop in a bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to print lines from a file in the below for loop:

```
SET my-file="C:\tmp\xxx.txt"
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%my-file%) do (
  echo line=%%a
)
```

Where:
C:\tmp\xxx.txt contains:

```
a
b
c
d
```

But the %my-file% is not expanded. How do I use a variable in the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By putting quotes around the path, the variable is treated as a string, not a path. So `%my-file%` will contains the name of the file, not it's content.

you can use the same code without the quotes (if the path allows it), or use type to read the file content :

```
SET my-file="C:\tmp\xxx.txt"
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type %my-file%') do (
  echo line=%%a
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works. If you have problems remove the echo off - which shows you that it is working.

This is your program in it's essense.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ("C:\tmp\xxx.txt") do echo line=%%a
```

And it should print, because someone put it in quotes, *C:\tmp\xxx.txt* as quotes mean the string is the content. No quote single or double is a filename. Single quote is a command.

If you need quotes you use UseBackQ option to move the single/double/no quote meanings around.

see `For /?`

Most of your batch is voodoo.

Extra unneeded brackets and sticking literals into variables.

Comment: He can also just leave the quotes out altogether and C:\temp\xxx.txt will be treated like a file that way. (Although if the filename has spaces, then yeah, he's going to need `usebackq`.)